weak convergence and pointwise implies $L_p$ convergence
Suppose $f_i \to f$ weakly in $L^p(X, M, \mu)$, $1 < p < \infty$, and that $f_i \to f$ pointwise $\mu$-a.e. Prove that $f_i^+ \to f^+$ and $f_i^- \to f^-$ weakly in $L^p$.
My proof:
Since $f^\pm = |f| \pm f$ then for a $g \in L^q(X,\mu)$ we have
\begin{align}
\int (f_i^+ -f^+) g d\mu \leq \frac{1}{2} \int |f_i-f| gd\mu + \frac{1}{2} \int (f_i -f)g d\mu
\end{align}
So I need to show that $f_i \to f$ in $L^p$.
Since $L^p$ is reflexive and $f_i\to f$ weakly, $f_i$ is bounded in $L^p$, that is , $\exists M>0$ such that $|f_i| \leq M,  \forall i$, so $|f|\leq M$ by Fatou's lemma.
Since $f^p \in L^1$,  the tail is finite, i.e., there is $A \subset X$ such that $\int_{A^c} |f|^p \leq \epsilon^p$, and $\mu(A) <\infty$. Now, we use Egorofs theorem to obtain a uniform convergence on $F\subset A$ and $\mu(A-F) <\epsilon$, now we have;
\begin{align*}
\int |f_i-f|^p &\leq \int_F |f_i-f|^p + \int_{A-F} |f_i -f|^p + \int_{A^c} |f_i -f|\\
& \epsilon \mu(F) + 2M \mu(A-F) + 2M \mu(A^c)\\
& \lesssim \epsilon
\end{align*}
Is boundedness the only reason the weak convergence holds?

Do we know anything about $X, \mu$?

@HyperbolicPDEfriend No, it is just a measure space.

This seems wrong. You estimated the integrand in $\int_{A-F} \lvert f_i - f \rvert^p$ pointwise, although you only have an $L^p$ bound. So $\mu(A-F)$ does not remain

@HyperbolicPDEfriend I used $|a- b|^p \leq 2^{p-1}(|a|^p + |b|^p)$. Also, the bound I used is the one we get from the weak convergence (Banach-Alaoglu) from the point wise convergence.

But then why does $\mu(A-F)$ remain. The bound from Banach-Alaoglu is for the norm, not pointwise.

Also to correct myself: The bound is obtained by Banach Steinhaus and not by Banach Alaoglu.

@HyperbolicPDEfriend Do you suggest another approach ?

I thought about writing $f^+=f\chi_{f>0}$, same for $f_i$. But I have Not come up with an Argument yet.

@Mr.Proof: your idea is correct but the execution is not quite right. You want to show that $\lim_n\int_X g_nh=\int_Xgh$ for all $h\in L_q$ and $g_n=f^{\pm}_n$, $g=g^{\pm}$. I wrote a solution with as many details as possible.

In general, the statement in the title of the OP is false. In $((0,\infty),\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}),m)$, $m$ is Lebesgue measure, define $f_n(x)=\frac1{x-n}\mathbb{1}_{(1,\infty)}(x-n)$. $f_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$ pointwise and for any $g\in L_2$,
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_0f_n(x)g(x)\,dx&=\int^\infty_{n+1}\frac{g(x)}{x-n}\,dx=\int^\infty_1\frac{g(x+n)}{x}\,dx\\
&\leq\Big(\int^\infty_0|g(x+n)|^2\,dx\big)^{1/2}=\Big(\int^\infty_{n}|g(x)|^2\,dx\big)^{1/2}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0
\end{align}
Yet, as $\|f_n\|_2=1$., $f_n$ does not converge in $L_2$.

The  problem described in the body of the OP however,  is of a different nature, and the answer to that is in the affirmative.
The assumption $f_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}f$ $\mu$-a.s. implies that $f^{\pm}_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}f^{\pm}$ $\mu$-a.s.
As pointed out by the OP, the $L_p$-weak convergence of $f_n$ implies that $f_n$ is $L_p$-bounded. Since $f^{\pm}_n\leq |f_n|$, it follows that $(f^{\pm}_n:n\in\mathbb{N})$ is $L_p$-bounded. The conclusion follows from the following result:

Theorem: If $1<p<\infty$, $(g_n:n\in\mathbb{N})$ is $L_p$-bounded and $g_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}g$ $\mu$-a.s., then $g_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}g$ weakly in $L_p$.

This result is discussed in Hewitt., E, and Stromberg., K., Real and Abstract Analysis, GTM, Springer Verlag, Berlin Heidelberg, 1965, pp. 207.

Here is a proof using similar arguments as those provided in the OP.
Let $M=\sup_n\|g_n\|_p$.
Let $q$ be the conjugate of $p$, i.e., $\frac1p+\frac1q=1$. Fix $h\in L_q$
We show that $\lim_n\int_X g_nh\,d\mu=\int_X gh\,d\mu$.
Given $\varepsilon>0$, there is  $\delta>0$ such that
$$\|h\mathbb{1}_E\|_q<\frac{\varepsilon}{3M}\quad\text{whenever}\quad \mu(E)<\delta$$
Since $\{|h|=0\}=\bigcap_n\{|h|\leq\frac1n\}$ and $\lim_n\int_{\{|h|\leq\frac1n\}}|h|^q\,d\mu=0$
There is $n_\varepsilon\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$\|h\mathbb{1}_{\{|h|\leq\frac1{n_\varepsilon}\}}\|_q<\frac{\varepsilon}{6M}$$
The set  $A_{\varepsilon}=\{|h|>\frac1{n_\varepsilon}\}$ has finite measure: $\mu(A_\varepsilon)\leq n_\varepsilon\|h\|^q_q<\infty$. Bu Egorov's theorem, there exists $B\subset A_\varepsilon$ such that $\mu(A_\varepsilon\setminus B)<\delta$ so that on $B$, $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly. Thus, there is $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for $n\geq N$
$$\|(g_n-g)\mathbb{1}_{B}\|_u<\frac{\varepsilon}{3\|h\|_q(\mu(B))^{1/p}}$$
Putting things together, we have that for all $n\geq N$
\begin{align}
\Big|\int (g-g_n)h\,d\mu\Big|&\leq \int_{A_\varepsilon}|g-g_n||h|\,d\mu + \int_{X\setminus A_\varepsilon}|g-g_n||h|\,d\mu\\
&\leq \int_{B}|g-g_n||h|\,d\mu+ \int_{A_\varepsilon\setminus B}|g-g_n||h|\,d\mu +\|g-g_n\|_p\|h\mathbb{1}_{X\setminus A_\varepsilon}\|_q\\
&\leq \|(g-g_n)\mathbb{1}_B\|_p\|h\|_q+\|g-g_n\|_p\|h\mathbb{1}_{A_\varepsilon\setminus B}\|_q+\frac{\varepsilon}{3}\\
&<\frac{\varepsilon}{3}+\frac{\varepsilon}{3}+\frac{\varepsilon}{3}
\end{align}
Hence $g_n$ converges to $g$ weakly in $L_p$.
